# How to use SQL_ASCII encoding in a rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, encoding, character-encoding

I have to connect to a legacy postgres database which has **ENCODING = 'SQL_ASCII';**.

How do I set this encoding in my rails app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set this in your database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: sql_ascii
  database: appname_development
  username: root
  password:
  host: localhost
```

Comment: Note: Order seems to matter: make sure your encoding is specified before your database name - this is what appears to have been causing the error for me.